# Can i pass smart pointers as function argument for generating vertex arrays

Tags: c++, opengl

Can i pass unique pointer as function argument instead of a raw pointer or an array

```
    unsigned int* m_VAO;
    m_VAO = (new unsigned int(totalNumberOfPies));
    glGenVertexArrays(totalNumberOfPies, m_VAO);
```

instead of m_VAO being a raw pointer can this be a smart unique pointer ?

Comment: @Rabbid76 instead of std::unique_ptr<unsigned int> , i should write  td::unique_ptr<GLuint>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define you `m_VAO` as `std::unique_ptr<GLuint[]>` and when you want to pass the pointer managed by the smart pointer, you would use `get()` to retrieve that raw pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<GLuint[]> m_VAO;

m_VAO = std::make_unique<GLuint[]>(totalNumberOfPies);

glGenVertexArrays(totalNumberOfPies, m_VAO.get());
```

A `std::unique_ptr<GLuint[]>` would only make sense if you also define a custom destructor for it, that calls the corresponding OpenGL function. To free the vertex arrays again. And even then it might be questionable if that is the right approach.

Furthermore, you only pass a smart pointer to a function (or write a function to accept a smart pointer) if that function is about to claim ownership, either directly, or pass it somewhere where the ownership is claimed.

If you don't do that then the question is why you want to use a smart pointer for that instead of an `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<GLuint> m_VAO;

m_VAO.resize(totalNumberOfPies);

glGenVertexArrays(m_VAO.size(), m_VAO.data());
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can i pass unique pointer as function argument instead of a raw pointer [to OpenGL functions]

No. OpenGL is specified in terms of a C-like language, and the implementations are just libraries following the platform's C ABI. OpenGL only uses "raw" pointers, and cannot deal with C++ objects at all.

You of course can manage the pointers (and the memory they point to) in C++ objects like smart or unique pointers, ort `std::vector` or whatever. And you can write wrapper functions for the GL functions which directly can work with such objects, but on the OpenGL level, "raw" pointers must be used in any case.

> or an array

That's actually not how C/C++ works. Using the name of an array as expression evaluates to a pointer to the first element of that array, so just raw pointers are passed in any case.

Comment: Even if `glGenVertexArrays` would be part of a c++ library, it would be unlikely that it would have a smart pointer as argument, because `glGenVertexArrays` only works on the pointer, but does not claim ownership on it.